# How to convert bitmap to grayscale by pixel intensity using GDI?

Tags: delphi, winapi, bitmap, gdi, grayscale

I'm looking for the simple solution of how to convert the 32-bit bitmap to grayscale using GDI (not GDI+). Is there a possibility e.g. by changing the bitmap's pallete or something ?

Of course there is plenty of examples in Delphi like [this one](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=437), but I'm looking for a WinAPI function which would do this without iteration through the lines.

Comment: I don't know about single GDI function which would do that nor about palette conversion, but the third function from the link you've mentioned do that. I guess you afraid of performance don't you ?

Comment: It's not only about performance, I'm looking for an easier solution (maybe by converting palette or something).

Comment: 32-bit bitmap doesn't contain palette.

Comment: Iterating through the scanlines is the answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't found any single GDI function doing this. The easiest way, as David mentioned in his comment, is to scan each line and compute the pixel colors. What you are looking for is probably the [`luminance`](http://www.scantips.com/lumin.html) formula.

There are few variations of this formula and in the following example I've used the one recommended by the [`ITU`](http://www.itu.int), see [`this document`](http://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.601-6-200701-S!!PDF-E.pdf#page=2) section 2.5.1. As I found somewhere, this formula is used e.g. even by well known Adobe Photoshop. The following code example supports and expects only 24-bit pixel format bitmaps as an input:

```
procedure BitmapGrayscale(ABitmap: TBitmap);
type
  PPixelRec = ^TPixelRec;
  TPixelRec = packed record
    B: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    R: Byte;
  end;
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Gray: Byte;
  Pixel: PPixelRec;
begin
  for Y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    Pixel := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      Gray := Round((0.299 * Pixel.R) + (0.587 * Pixel.G) + (0.114 * Pixel.B));
      Pixel.R := Gray;
      Pixel.G := Gray;
      Pixel.B := Gray;
      Inc(Pixel);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks TLama, it seems there's really no WinAPI function for this.

Comment: Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24Bit; // needed for gray scaling

Answer (score 5):

You can create a paletted DIB Section, 8 bits per pixel and 256 colors, and initialize palette to shades of grey { 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, ... { 255, 255, 255 }.

A single GDI `BitBlt` into this bitmap will grey your original image out. Here is the code snippet (in C++, ATL and WTL - but you should get the idea).

```
CWindowDC DesktopDc(NULL);
CDC BitmapDc;
ATLVERIFY(BitmapDc.CreateCompatibleDC(DesktopDc));
CBitmap Bitmap;
CTempBuffer<BITMAPINFO> pBitmapInfo;
const SIZE_T nBitmapInfoSize = sizeof (BITMAPINFO) + 256 * sizeof (RGBQUAD);
pBitmapInfo.AllocateBytes(nBitmapInfoSize);
ZeroMemory(pBitmapInfo, nBitmapInfoSize);
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = 320;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = 240;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 8;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 240 * 320;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 256;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 256;
for(SIZE_T nIndex = 0; nIndex < 256; nIndex++)
{
    pBitmapInfo->bmiColors[nIndex].rgbRed = (BYTE) nIndex;
    pBitmapInfo->bmiColors[nIndex].rgbGreen = (BYTE) nIndex;
    pBitmapInfo->bmiColors[nIndex].rgbBlue = (BYTE) nIndex;
}
Bitmap.Attach(CreateDIBSection(DesktopDc, pBitmapInfo, 0, DIB_RGB_COLORS, NULL, 0));
ATLVERIFY(Bitmap);
BitmapDc.SelectBitmap(Bitmap);
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is what greys it out:
ATLVERIFY(BitBlt(BitmapDc, 0, 0, 320, 240, DesktopDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY));
////////////////////////////////////////////////
ATLVERIFY(BitBlt(DesktopDc, 0, 240, 320, 240, BitmapDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY));
```

Comment: Will GDI allow to abandon reserved system colors from halftone palette?

Comment: This makes a fully grayscale palette with 256 shades of gray, no system colors.

Comment: @RomanR.: I don't understand where the initial bitmap (the one to be converted) comes into play here. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @UliGerhardt: it is assumed to be selected into DC passed as 6th argument to BitBlt call. Here, it is desktop picture, so you don't see it as bitmap.