# Win32 bitmap color to grayscale

Tags: c++, winapi

i am writing a program that opens, rotates, scales,invert color,converts to grayscale and save bitmap (.bmp)
But i dont seem to get the the converting to greyscale(ie black and white) working every other code works perfectly...

the code for my color inversion is below...

```
 case 3:
{
    hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
    GetClientRect(hWnd,&rt);
    BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rt.right,rt.bottom,hdc,0,0,NOTSRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,hdc);
}
```

this seem to work but getting the DC and trying to change it to grey scale isn't working using BitBlt...
I would like to get an idea on how to get the DC and convert it to grey-scale...
winapi
thanks...

Comment: Isn't color inversion something like `255-x`?  Right now, you're doing `~x`, which isn't the same computation at all.  While both of these are "inversions" of color, the former inverts the color scale, whereas the latter inverts the pixel bit patterns.

Comment: what does `GetLastError()` return after the `BitBlt`?

Comment: BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rt.right,rt.bottom,hdc,0,0,NOTSRCCOPY); works correctly for inverting the bitmap color... what doesn't seem to work is using the bitblt to convert the image to grayscale... i tried BitBlt(hdc,0,0,rt.right,rt.bottom,hdc,0,0,BLACKNESS|WHITNESS); but its not working... maybe i'm not suppose to use bitblt...

Answer (score 2):

Raymond Chen gives a [complete example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090714-00/?p=17503) of using the color mapper in GDI to convert a color image to grayscale using BitBlt.

Comment: + another code snippet in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559341/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-grayscale-by-pixel-intensity-using-gdi